# C get file without having to specify the full path in unix

Tags: c, filepath

I am trying to include the relative path to a file in a program written in C. Currently for the program I have

```
createShader(&shader,"/Users/myUsername/Documents/Programming/OpenGL/shaders/shaderFile.glsl");
```

which is not portable. What I want is What I want is

```
createShader(&skyboxShader, "shaders/shaderFile.glsl");.
```

The shaders directory is one directory below the directory of my main program. My file structure is

```
program
    \include
    \src
        -> main.c
        -> main.h
        \shaders
            -> shaderFile.glsl
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the program know the base directory, it [can change the process working directory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/chdir.2.html) to the base directory. And if the process current working directory already is correct then it doesn't have to do anything.

Comment: Either what @JoachimPileborg says or use `openat()` to open a file relative to a directory. I have no idea if this is possible with the `createShader()` API, however it works.

Comment: Did you try? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: The resource did not load. Getting the directory using getenv("PWD") I got /Users/myUsername. So shortening it to /Documents/Programming/OpenGL/shaders/shaderFile.glsl works

Comment: When your program is executed, it only knows about the directory in which the user executes it. it neither knows nor cares anything about the directory structure where it was compiled. And the executable could be stored anywhere on the system, or be a hard or soft link to the actual program stored somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notion of portability is too weak. Coding absolute paths in a program is generally a bad idea, but making it relative to the source seems equally flawed.  What I would suggest is the you incorporate a simple search path algorithm, one that looks first in the current working directory, then perhaps in the users home directory in some dotted subdirectory (hidden), and then as directed by some command line argument or environment variable.  A general search path function, assuming someone has not already implemented it, would be useful in most programs you write.